# Limit an MSI laptop battery charging to 80%

Tags: laptop, acpi, battery

[How can I limit battery charging to 80% capacity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity)

Above thread provides several solutions for ThinkPad laptops. Mine is an **MSI** GF72 8RE-032. The Windows 10 drivers&utility pack seems to provide the feature. However nothing is to be found for my Debian installation. Is there a tool to extend battery life, even in early development?

In other words, I am looking for **any** way to limit battery charging to below 100%. My BIOS doesn't provide the feature. Some of my colleagues **unplug and plug the power adapter multiple times per day** to achieve longer battery life. Is there really no other solution?

If my battery was easily removable, I would just charge it to 80% and keep it on a shelf. But, like many modern laptops, this procedure involves disassembling the machine.